# Backbone multiple instance of a same view used inside tabs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm working with backbone I'm trying to create a tab view that uses inside panels to render in this case same instance of a table view. My problem is that when the second instance renders removes the first one even though I've been debuging the code and I can see 2 diferent objects for each view.

Here is the code to create object:

```
var tabs = new Dashboard.Tab({
   id: 'reward-tab',
   panels: [{
      id: 'active-panel',
      active: true,
      label: 'Actives',
      content: new Dashboard.Table({
         id: 'active-table',
         model: new Dashboard.TableModel(null,{
            active: true
         })
      })
   },{
     id: 'dismiss-panel',
     active: false,
     label: 'Not active',
     content: new Dashboard.Table({
        id: 'dismiss-table',
        model: new Dashboard.TableModel(null,{
          active: false
        })
     })
   }]
});
```

Tab view code

```
Dashboard.Tab = Backbone.View.extend({
    template : Handlebars.templates['tabs.hbs'],
    panels: [],

    events: {
        'click .nav-tabs li a' : 'onTabClick'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.id = this.options.id;
        this.panels = this.options.panels;
    },

    onTabClick: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
    },

    render:function(){
        //Renders places holders
        this.$el.html(this.template({
            id: this.id,
            tabs : this.panels
        }));

        $.each(this.panels, function(index, panel){
           if(panel && panel.content) {
               panel.content.on('ready', function(){
                   $('#' + panel.id).append(panel.content.el);
               });
           }
        });
    }
});
```

Table code:

```
Dashboard.Table = Backbone.View.extend({

    tableId: 'my-table',

    initialize: function() {
        var me = this;
        this.tableId = this.options.id;

        this.model.fetch({reset: true}).done(function () {
            me.render();
        });    
        ....
    },
    render: function() {
        ....
        this.trigger("ready");
    }
});
```

Like I said, my problem seem that for some reason the second view its removing the html for the first instance and only rendering the second one.

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a AHA moment and I thought the problem could be that I wasn't defining a different el to each view.

When you don't Backbone creates the view inside a generic div element so in this case what I did was to add a new element for each and that made the trick.

The Fix:

```
var tabs = new Dashboard.Tab({
   id: 'reward-tab',
   panels: [{
      id: 'active-panel',
      active: true,
      label: 'Actives',
      content: new Dashboard.Table({
         id: 'active-table',
         el: $('<div class="active-table"></div>'),
         model: new Dashboard.TableModel(null,{
            active: true
         })
      })
   },{
     id: 'dismiss-panel',
     active: false,
     label: 'Not active',
     content: new Dashboard.Table({
        id: 'dismiss-table',
        el: $('<div class="not-active-table"></div>'),
        model: new Dashboard.TableModel(null,{
          active: false
        })
     })
   }]
});
```